# ARKit - Programmatically 'billboard' (look at camera) elements added in Reality composer

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I am using Xcode (11.3.1) to make an AR app using ARKit. I am adding objects, text etc. in Reality Composer. I can then access these objects by loading the scene and objects in `ViewController.swift`.

I would like to make some of these objects constantly face the camera.

I am aware that I could add a look-at-camera 'behaviour' in Reality Composer but I don't want to do this for 2 reasons;

a) it only allows you to add in such a way that you the effect lasts for a certain amount of time (max 5 mins)

b) I would like to know how to do this programmatically.

I am aware there are a range of solutions to billboarding in ARKit provided on here, most of which are included in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579083/arkit-make-virtual-3d-objects-to-point-towards-camera) but all of these solutions involve using SceneKit.

My question is therefore - is it possible to implement this 'billboarding' effect without using SceneKit? Is there a way to do it in RealityKit only? It would seem that there is since you can include this effect by adding it as a behaviour using Reality Composer (which as far as I can tell doesn't require SceneKit, but I could be wrong). I have tried to dig down into the Reality Composer scene to understand how billboarding is achieved there but you can see in [the response to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004402/reality-kit-where-are-behaviours-created-in-reality-composer-stored-in-the-r) the 'behaviours' are not exposed so I cannot see how this is achieved.

My 'from scratch' approach would be to understand the position/rotation of the [camera](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera) but I am too inexperienced to know where to start with that. Essentially I am looking for the equivalent of `SCNBillboardConstraint` but without using SceneKit, perhaps that's not possible?

Answer (score 2):

```
extension Entity {
    /// Billboards the entity to the targetPosition which should be provided in world space.
    func billboard(targetPosition: SIMD3<Float>) {
        look(at: targetPosition, from: position(relativeTo: nil), relativeTo: nil)
    }
}
```

---

```
var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
```

---

```
  arView.scene.subscribe(to: SceneEvents.Update.self) { [self] _ in
                            箭头.billboard(targetPosition: arView.cameraTransform.translation)
                         }.store(in: &subscriptions)
```

---

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656611

Comment: This code flips the entity backward.