# Receiving Xcode notification on Reality Composer animation end

Tags: swift, xcode, realitykit, reality-composer

I have the following Reality Composer project that loads properly. As you can see, when the animation completes, it should notify with the keyword "attackComplete".

How do I get this notification?

[image]

```
import RealityKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadOrcAttack()
        arView.session.delegate = self
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
        print("done")
    }
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        print(anchors)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With Reality Composer's notifications you can implement two scenarios:

### Action listener

This is your case and it's easy to implement using

`public var onAction: ((RealityKit.Entity?) -> Swift.Void)?`.

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    let scene = try! Experience.loadScene()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(scene)
        
        scene.actions.attackCompleted.onAction = notificationID   // listener
    }
 
    fileprivate func notificationID(_ entity: Entity?) {        
         print(scene.actions.attackCompleted.identifier)
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is one more [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75020799/if-i-assign-a-sound-in-reality-composer-can-i-stop-it-programmatically-in-reali/75031036#75031036) of how `.onAction` ***completion handler*** can be used.

### Trigger for action

When you need to notify Reality Composer's scene to play an action use the following scenario:

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    let scene = try! Experience.loadScene()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(scene)
    }
    
    @IBAction func press(_ sender: UIButton) {
        scene.notifications.spinner.post()            // trigger for action
    }
}
```

or use a subscript for `[NAME.NotificationTrigger]`:

```
@IBAction func press(_ sender: NSButton) {
    scene.notifications.allNotifications[0].post()
}
```

[image]

Here's one more example of how [.post()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75312348/can-i-control-reality-composer-behaviors-in-realitykit/75316409#75316409) ***instance method*** can be used.

### P. S.

If you need more info, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004402/where-are-behaviours-created-in-reality-composer-stored-in-rcproject).

Comment: Your case you set it up to specifically print that statement after a time interval. I need something like "didReceiveNotification" or something like a listener function, or is that not available? I mean, I can send the notification ,so how do I receive it?

Comment: I think the answer is an implementation of the following: let newUpdate = arView.scene.subscribe(to: SceneEvents.Update.self

Comment: IE, how do I get an input to xcode of "attackComplete"

Comment: It did seem to work in preliminary tests. Thank you.