# If I assign a sound in Reality Composer, can I stop it programmatically in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit, reality-composer

I assign a sound to a scene in Reality Composer as in the image below

[image]

I would like to create an UIButton that can be pressed to stop the sound. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created three Reality Composer actions for box scene: they are `Play Sound`, `Spin` and [Notify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71115018/receiving-xcode-notification-on-reality-composer-animation-end). As you can see ***loop playback*** is turned ON.

[image]

### SwiftUI

My code is as simple as that. Primary `stop()` methods are for immediate stop of audio and animation. Secondary `stop()` methods are the content of completion handler for `onAction` property.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    
    @State var completion: ((Entity?) -> ()) = { _ in }
    @State var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    @State var boxScene = try! Experience.loadBox()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ARViewContainer(arView: $arView, boxScene: $boxScene)
               .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Button("Stop") {
                    boxScene.steelBox?.stopAllAudio()              // 1
                    boxScene.steelBox?.stopAllAnimations()         // 1
                    print("Actions are stopped.")
                    
                    completion = {
                        $0?.stopAllAudio()                         // 2
                        $0?.stopAllAnimations()                    // 2
                        $0?.scale = [1,15,1]
                        print("Both actions were completely stopped.")
                    }

                    boxScene.actions.occured.onAction = completion
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's an ordinary binding.

```
struct ARViewContainer : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var arView: ARView
    @Binding var boxScene: Experience.Box
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxScene)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

Note that `Notify` action is the last one in the sequence. After what time the secondary `stop()` methods will be applied (I mean the content of the completion handler), depends on the duration of the audio file or animation (my audio's duration is 14 sec).

[image]

### UIKit

UIKit solution is somehow different and slightly simpler.

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController : UIViewController {       
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    let boxScene = try! Experience.loadBox()
    var completion: ((Entity?) -> Void)? = { _ in }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let rect = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 50)
        let stopButton = UIButton(frame: rect)
        stopButton.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
        stopButton.addTarget(self, 
                           action: #selector(stopPlayingAudioAndAnime), 
                              for: .touchUpInside)
        arView.addSubview(stopButton)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxScene)
    }

    @objc private func stopPlayingAudioAndAnime() {            
        boxScene.steelBox?.stopAllAudio()                     // 1
        boxScene.steelBox?.stopAllAnimations()                // 1
        
        completion = { entity in
            entity?.stopAllAudio()                            // 2
            entity?.stopAllAnimations()                       // 2
            print("Completely Stopped")
        }           
        boxScene.actions.occured.onAction = completion
    }
}
```

### P. S.

However, if you'll be using `Play Music` action (in other words, on the scene basis, not on the object basis, like `Play Sound` action), you can implement your idea this way:

```
arView.scene.anchors[0].children[0].stopAllAudio()
    
completion = { entity in
    entity?.scene?.anchors[0].children[0].stopAllAudio()
}
```

Comment: Can I use `arView.scene.anchors[0].stopAllAudio()` ?

Comment: Nice! Additionally, I have 2 question: 1) Why do you need to add `.children[0]` to the code? and 2) Can I use `.playAudio()` to resume playback after stopping?

Comment: 1) It's hierarchy. AnchorEntity doesn't have needed components. 2) post another question.