# Can I use .playAudio() to resume playback after stopping?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit, reality-composer

From the question in this  [If I assign a sound in Reality Composer, can I stop it programmatically in RealityKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75020799/if-i-assign-a-sound-in-reality-composer-can-i-stop-it-programmatically-in-reali), I would like to use method to resume playback after `Play Music`.

Can I do that?

Now, I use this command in stopAudio function to stop the music.

```
func stopAudio() {
    if arView.scene.anchors.count > 0 {
        if arView.scene.anchors[0].isAnchored {
            arView.scene.anchors[0].children[0].stopAllAudio()
        }
    }
}
```

If I want `arView.scene.anchors[0]` to replay the music again, which command should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Spatial Audio Playback in RealityKit

Since RealityKit for iOS isn't able to control parameters of Reality Composer 1.5 behaviors, the best strategy for controlling audio is to create a programmatic [AudioPlaybackController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/audioplaybackcontroller). To feed your audio file to the controller, export `.rcproject` scene to `.usdz` format and use [unzipping trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55544185/how-to-generate-usdz-file-again-from-zip-file/55631922#55631922) to extract the `.aiff`, `.caf` or `.mp3` sound file. When loading audio for playback, you can choose between `spatial` and `non-spatial` audio experience.

In this answer you'll find solutions on how to control Spatial Audio in `iOS` and `visionOS`.

### UIKit version

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

extension ViewController {

    private func loadAudio() {
        do {
            let resource = try AudioFileResource.load(
                                                named: "planetarium07.caf",
                                                   in: nil,
                                            inputMode: .spatial,
                                      loadingStrategy: .preload,
                                           shouldLoop: true)

            self.controller = entity.prepareAudio(resource)
            self.controller?.speed = 0.9
            self.controller?.fade(to: .infinity, duration: 2)

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var uiView: UIView! 
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    private var entity = Entity()
    private var controller: AudioPlaybackController? = nil
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        uiView.backgroundColor = .systemCyan
        
        let boxScene = try! Experience.loadBox()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxScene)
        
        let anchor = boxScene.anchor
        anchor?.addChild(entity)
        
        self.loadAudio()
    }
    @IBAction func playMusic(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.controller?.play()
    }
    @IBAction func stopMusic(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.controller?.pause()
        // self.controller?.stop()
    }
}
```

### SwiftUI iOS version

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {       
    @State var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    @State var controller: AudioPlaybackController? = nil
    @State var entity = Entity()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ARViewContainer(arView: $arView, 
                            entity: $entity).ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Play") { loadSound(); controller?.play() }
                Button("Stop") { controller?.stop() }
            }
        }
    }
    func loadSound() {
        do {
            let resource = try AudioFileResource.load(
                                                named: "planetarium07.caf",
                                                   in: nil,
                                            inputMode: .spatial,
                                      loadingStrategy: .preload,
                                           shouldLoop: true)    
            self.controller = entity.prepareAudio(resource)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var arView: ARView
    @Binding var entity: Entity
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {

        let boxScene = try! Experience.loadBox()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxScene)
        
        let anchor = boxScene.anchor
        anchor?.addChild(entity)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

### SwiftUI visionOS version

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

class Audio : Entity {
    let resource: AudioFileResource
    
    init(_ named: String) {
        resource = try! AudioFileResource.load(named: named)
    }
    func setupSpatialSound(pinnedTo: ModelEntity) {
        self.spatialAudio = SpatialAudioComponent()
        self.spatialAudio?.gain = -15             // decibels
        self.addChild(pinnedTo)
    }
    func playSpatialSound() {
        self.playAudio(resource)
    }
    func stopSpatialSound() {
        self.stopAllAudio()
    }
    @MainActor required init() {
        fatalError("Hasn't been implemented yet")
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var counter = 1
    let cube = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.05))
    let audio = Audio("AudioFile")
    
    init() {
        cube.components[InputTargetComponent.self] = .init()
        cube.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
        
        audio.setupSpatialSound(pinnedTo: cube)
        audio.playSpatialSound()
    }
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            content.add(audio)
        }
        .gesture(
            SpatialTapGesture()
                .targetedToEntity(cube)
                .onEnded { _ in
                    counter += 1
                    
                    if (counter % 2) == 0 {
                        audio.stopSpatialSound()
                    } else if (counter % 2) == 1 {
                        audio.playSpatialSound()
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the code compatible for the SwiftUI interface?

Comment: Of course, you can run it in SwiftUI.

Comment: Sorry, where does the `.caf` file should be in the Xcode? and Is it necessary for setting the music in the Reality Composer?

Comment: I have already import the `.caf` file in my Xcode project, but when I click the button, it shows **RealityKit.AudioResource.FileNotFound**.

Comment: Drag and drop `.caf` or `.aiff` file into Xcode's `navigator pane`. Make sure you ticked its Target Membership (check it in `inspector pane`). Restart Xcode.

Comment: Double-check the file name.

Comment: Is the `AudioFileResource` is usable for `.mp3` file?

Comment: @kkk yes it is.