# Can I control Reality Composer behaviors in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit, reality-composer

I would like to make a button using SwiftUI. When the button is pressed, the model will hide. I have already read the tutorial in this link ([Creating a Trigger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/creating-a-trigger)), but I don't know how to control it programmatically.

Here is my code:

```
struct VocabView : View {
    
    @State private var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            ARViewContainer(arView: $arView)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Button("hide") {
                    hide()
                }    
            }
        }
    }
    
    func hide() {
        let demoScene = try! Experience1.loadDemo()
        if arView.scene.anchors.count > 0 {
            if arView.scene.anchors[0].isAnchored {
                demoScene.notifications.hide.post()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer2: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var arView: ARView
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let demoScene = try! Experience1.loadDemo()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            arView.scene.anchors.append(demoScene)
        }
        
        return arView
        
    } 
}
```

Here is the configuration in Reality Composer:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading your model twice – at first in `makeUIView()` method and secondly in `hide()` method. Try my version.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {

    @State private var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    @State private var scene = try! Experience.loadBox()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            ARViewContainer(arView: $arView, scene: $scene)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Hide Model") { hideModel() }
            }
        }
    }
    private func hideModel() {
        if arView.scene.anchors.count > 0 {
            if arView.scene.anchors[0].isAnchored {
                scene.notifications.notify.post()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

```
struct ARViewContainer : UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var arView: ARView
    @Binding var scene: Experience.Box
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        arView.scene.anchors.append(scene)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

[image]